# Swift 3 : How to add a link in imessage?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm trying to add a link in iMessage Sticker app.  The link opens itunes sticker store page.  When I add these code in MessagesViewController.swift file, I get an error "'shared' is unvailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead". How to add the link properly?

```
 func clickMe(sender:UIButton!)
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id11111111")!)
    print("Button Clicked")
}
```

Comment: Does MessagesViewController is a subclass of UIViewViewContoller?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Xcode Build Settings,And search extension and change Value from Yes to No of "Require only App-extension-safe Api" after that you can access without any error.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "your url address")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS Extensions have some limitations so you can not access every API that you can reach from an app.

> Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions
>
> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is ineligible to participate in certain activities. An app extension cannot:
>
> Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object...

For more details take a look at this [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html)